# Prove that there exists a $x$ such that $c<x<b$ and $f(x)>f(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f: [a,b]$ is differentiable at $c$ in $(a,b)$ and the derivative of $f(x)$ at $c$ is greater than $0$.
>   Then, prove that there exists a $x$ such that $c<x<b$ and $f(x)>f(c)$.

It kinda seems like I will have to use mean value theorem.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements for the MVT (as $f$ here is only guaranteed to be differentiable *at* a point, rather than over the interval).  However, the statement makes intuitive sense...

Answer (score 3):

write down the definition of the derivative
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h}$$
if for all $h > 0$ we'd have $f(c+h) \leq f(c)$ that is $f(c+h) - f(c) \leq 0$ then the derivative at $c$ would be $\leq 0$ hence we have a contradiction proving your claim

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this directly from limits. We can take $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ so that the difference between the difference quotient and the derivative itself is quite small. Explicitly, $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\epsilon$$ If we take $$\epsilon=\frac{f'(c)}{2}$$ then we get $$0<\frac{f'(c)}{2}<\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}<\frac{3f'(c)}{2}$$ for all $x$ with $0<|x-c|<\min\{\delta,b-c\}$. Take an $x>c$ to find $$f(x)-f(c)>\frac{f'(c)}{2}(x-c)>0\implies f(x)>f(c)$$ as desired.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly: we're justified in choosing $\epsilon = \frac{f'(c)}{2}$ because we know, based on the limit definition, that there will be an $x$ such that the inequality is satisfied, right?

Comment: Right, and because $f'(c)/2$ is a positive number and hence a valid choice for $\epsilon$.